# PHP close connection after pcntl_fork

Tags: php, multiprocessing

I am trying to fetch some data through an api using different process to do all the request at the same time.

It's working fine but I have a lot of memory leaks in the script (I am using shared memory segment to store the results fetched by every process)

The code I use to create shared memory segment looks like this (I just put the minimum code useful to understand the problem):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    if (getmypid() == $parent_pid) {
        $process_pool[] = pcntl_fork();
        // Get the memory segment where the process set the status of data fetching and set it to KO
        if (getmypid() == $parent_pid) {
            //I am creating memory here
            echo '<br>i : ' . $i . ' mypid : ' . getmypid() . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get :

> i : 0 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 1 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 2 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 3 mypid : 11128
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:31 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:31 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
>   i : 0 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 1 mypid : 11128
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:34 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
>   i : 0 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 1 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 2 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 3 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 4 mypid : 11128
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:34 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
>   i : 0 mypid : 11128
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:34 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
>   i : 0 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 1 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 2 mypid : 11128
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2018 11:07:34 +0000 Connection: close X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.2 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
>   i : 0 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 1 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 2 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 3 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 4 mypid : 11128
>
> i : 5 mypid : 11128

It looks obvious that the problem comes from connection being closed for whatever reason, what is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd highly recommend to use pthreads: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i wanted to use pthread at first but the problem is we can't use it outside of CLI. This code is made to run on apache server.

Comment: OMG using threads to **fix** a memory leak????!!!!!

Comment: I see code for forking, I don't see where it called from, I don't see where the shm is being allocated, nor where it is being freed, nor what is producing the HTTP headers in the output. Ultimately this about flow control and we can't see the elements here - so can't guess at the answer. However I will note that using shm for this seems like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Hi, as far as i know there is no other way to do asynchron in php. Shared memory segment is the best way here to share data between process. I didn't put code creating shm and freeing it because it's not relevant. The point is that too many segment are created because script starts at the beginning of loop again each time TCP connection is closed.